# For each array value check if it is in a json array. If it is skip json array for next iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays, json

Sorry if the title is a little confusing. Not sure how else to put it...

I have an array of dates:

```
var dateRange = ["2017-08-21", "2017-08-22", "2017-08-23", "2017-08-24", "2017-08-25", "2017-08-26", "2017-08-27"];
```

I also have a json array of data which contains a date.

```
var jsonArray = [
    {
         date: "2017-08-21",
         edit: false,
         text: "some text"
    },
    {
         date: "2017-08-23", //notice skipped 2017-08-22
         edit: false,
         text: "some text"
    },
    ...
];
```

So what I want to do is check `jsonArray` for each date that is in `dateRange`, and if `dateRange` isn't present for any of `jsonArray`'s dates, do something.

The way I was doing is was doing an `indexOf` for each date in `dateRange` but I realized that for instance `"2017-08-23"` compared to `"2017-08-21"` would be triggered, but I don't want this, as `"2017-08-23"` is actually present in the array...

Does that make sense?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: *"I also have a json array"* - No, you have an array of objects; there's no JSON in this question. Anyway, I don't understand your note about why `indexOf()` didn't work, because `.indexOf()` wouldn't match "2017-08-23" with "2017-08-21"  - can you perhaps [edit] your question to show the code you tried?

Comment: @nnnnnn well the issue is that if the `indexOf()` fails, which it will since comparing `2017-08-23` to `2017-08-21` is false... I want to check if the array element is no where in the array of objects.. Does that make a little more sense?

Comment: Not really. If you are iterating over the items in `jsonArray` and want to test if the date for the current item is not in the other array you can say `if (dateRange.indexOf(jsonArray[i].date) === -1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if i got it but you want to check if any item in `jsonArray` contains a date in `dateRange` right?

You can do something like:

`let yourKey = jsonArray.some((item) => {
    return dateRange.contains(item.date)
})`

This will return `true` to `yourKey` if any jsonArray item date matches a dateRange date. Is that it?

[EDIT]

If you want to check every json array item and do something you can do:

```
jsonArray.forEach((item) => {
    if (dateRange.contains(item.date)) {
        // The date is in the array, do something
    } else {
        // The date is not in the array, do something else.
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Naive approach which is O(n^2) would be:

```js
var jsonArray = [
    {
         date: "2017-08-21",
         edit: false,
         text: "some text"
    },
    {
         date: "2017-08-23", //notice skipped 2017-08-22
         edit: false,
         text: "some text"
    },
];

var dateRange = ["2017-08-21", "2017-08-22", "2017-08-23", "2017-08-24", "2017-08-25", "2017-08-26", "2017-08-27"];

for(var i = 0; i < dateRange.length; i++){
   for(var j = 0; j < jsonArray.length; j++){
      if(dateRange[i] == jsonArray[j].date){
        console.log("Date Found:" + dateRange[i]);
      }
   
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's like this:

```js
function DateRangeTester(startDateString, endDateString){
  var start = new Date(startDateString).getTime();
  var end = new Date(endDateString).getTime();
  this.test = function(testDateString, passFunc, failFunc, passFuncContext, failFuncContext){
    var pc = passFuncContext || this;
    var fc = failFuncContext || this;
    var test = new Date(testDateString).getTime();
    if(test >= start && test <= end){
      passFunc.call(pc, testDateString);
    }
    else{
      failFunc.call(fc, testDateString);
    }
  }
}
var range = new DateRangeTester('2017-08-21 00:00:00', '2017-08-27 00:00:00');
var jsonArray = [
  {
    date: '2017-08-21',
    edit: false,
    text: 'some text'
  },
  {
    date: '2017-08-28', // outside range
    edit: false,
    text: 'some text'
  },
  {
    date: '2017-08-23', //not sure I understand your comment
    edit: false,
    text: 'some text'
  },
  {
    date: '2017-08-20', // outside range
    edit: false,
    text: 'some text'
  }
];
for(var i=0,ds,l=jsonArray.length; i<l; i++){
  ds = jsonArray[i].date;
  range.test(ds+' 00:00:00', function(r){
    console.log(r+' passed the test');
  }, function(r){
    console.log(r+' failed the test');
  });
}
```